# Find a regex generic string and replace it with the same string enclosed in parenthesis - Latex and TeXStudio

Tags: regex, latex, bibtex, texstudio

I have made my BIB file and I am compiling my project using BIBTEX on TeXStudio.  In my particular case, I get an error when the reference entry has the month in the following format:

`month = jan,`

It should be `month = {jan},`

I tried searching using regular expressions and can succesfully find my targets but then i dont know how to replace (or add the `{mmm}`) to my search results. I am searching using the following expression: `= \w{3}`, which guarantees finding any month acronym and not a three letter word such as surname (Lee, Han, etc)

Is there a way to send the search result as an argument to the Replace box and I can just add the `{}` around it? instead of looking for each month manually and do the replacing one by one.

Thanks in advance for any help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Braces are wrong! Don't add them!

With bibtex, you should either write `month = jan` or `month = {1}`.

For more information https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386058/36296

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for pointing out that. I will see to it. I am exporting my references from Zotero using betterBibtex and that's how it does it. I assumed it was the right way. However I have to give the benefit of the doubt to my university's template since it's not exactly clean and free of errors

Comment: However, I'd still love to know how can I do what I was asking in the first place